# Media queries missing the screen using Breakpoint Sass

Tags: css, media-queries, susy-compass, breakpoint-sass, susy-sass

I'm using Susy 2 with breakpoint-sass to create my media queries.

It's outputting like:

```
@media (min-width: 1000px)
```

I'm wondering why the screen is missing? It should read:

```
@media screen (min-width: 1000px)
```

I'm trying to add css3-mediaqueries-js which isn't working and I think that might be why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breakpoint's default media type is `all`, which, per the CSS spec, can be omitted. We do this we do not want to assume any media type, doing so has led to the current situation we have now where media types are all but useless. If you would like to change your default media type in Breakpoint to `screen`, before including any breakpoint mixins, add the following to your Sass file:

`$breakpoint-default-media: screen;`

Answer (score 1):

This may help:
https://github.com/Team-Sass/breakpoint/wiki/Advanced-Media-Queries#media-types

If you're still stuck after that, could you edit your question to include the sass code that outputs that media query?